# NMP failes to load package but I can get it directly with URL

Tags: node.js, npm

After installing NODE.JS on my Windows 10/64 machine and attempting to test the NPM module I get the following:

from the log..:

```
verbose request id 639b6b02c53f25ad
http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/express
http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/express
verbose bad json <html><head><title>Page Not Found</title><head><body>Sorry, but I couldn't find the object you requested.</body></html>
21 error registry error parsing json
```

Clearly NPM sends the request to the repo for the express module but NPM cannot find it...yet if I type the url directly on the browser I do get the json for the package.

I am behind a proxy and I did set the proxy settings as per npm set config proxy and https-proxy [1](https://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/)

I should add however that my proxy uri doesn't end on the port but it has an additional string :xxxx/proxy.pac?p=xxxxx

I think I have done all I have read so far so I am looking for new hints (at the very least) to follow.

Comment: As a last recourse I removed the proxy and https-proxy entries from the config file (using `npm config rm proxy` and `npm config rm https-proxy` which I had set before (read post) and that resolved the issue. I re-ran `npm install [module] -g` and the module was correctly installed ...it appears the SSL not the PROXY was the original issue, adding the proxy settings just mudded the waters.

Comment: BTW I resolved the SSL issue by setting `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/` and `npm set strict-ssl false`